# The same snippet of code in Java takes very different times in two programs?

Tags: java, algorithm, runtime, genetic-algorithm, execution-time

Basically I have two heuristics based algorithms. I am using a snippet of code in both of them. The code takes in an incentives vector and gives out the value of cost function based on this vector. One part of the code produces an incentives vector. This part is different for the two algorithms. Another part of code calculates the cost function based on incentives vector. This part is word for word same for both algorithms. However, In one algorithm (GA based) it takes 5 to 10 seconds to execute that code while in the other, the same code takes more than 5 minutes. I don't understand how such a huge difference is even possible. Below is the part of the code which has different execution times. As evident, this part consists of basic for loops and simple mathematics. Values of all the other arrays are known and the aim is calculate the "CurrentInv".

```
long start6 = System.currentTimeMillis();
for(int a=0;a<_invIndex;a++){
    CurrentInv[a]=Invs[a];
    for (int i=0; i<no1;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<no1;j++){
            if(i!=j){
                for(int b=0; b<_destNe; b++){
                    if(countOD[i][j]>0){
                        if(i==b){
                            if(j==a){
                                CurrentInv[a]=CurrentInv[a]+onlyBike[i][j][0][(int)nSizeO[i][j]+1]*countOD[i][j]*x[i][j][0][(int)nSizeO[i][j]+1];
                            }
                        }}
                    if(countOD[i][j]>0){
                        if(nSizeO[i][j]!=0){
                            for(int k=1; k<(int)nSizeO[i][j]+1; k++){
                                if( jaggedO[i][j][k-1]==b){
                                    if( j==a){
                                        CurrentInv[a]=CurrentInv[a]+onlyBike[i][j][k][(int)nSizeO[i][j]+1]*countOD[i][j]*x[i][j][k][(int)nSizeO[i][j]+1];

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if(nSizeD[i][j]!=0){
                            for(int d=(int)nSizeO[i][j]+2; d<(int)nSizeD[i][j]+(int)nSizeO[i][j]+2; d++){
                                if( jaggedD[i][j][d-(int)nSizeO[i][j]-2]==b){
                                    if( j==a){
                                        CurrentInv[a]=CurrentInv[a]+onlyBike[i][j][d][(int)nSizeO[i][j]+1]*countOD[i][j]*x[i][j][d][(int)nSizeO[i][j]+1];

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if( i==b){
                            if(nSizeD[i][j]!=0){
                                for(int d=(int)nSizeO[i][j]+2; d<(int)nSizeD[i][j]+(int)nSizeO[i][j]+2; d++){
                                    if( jaggedD[i][j][d-(int)nSizeO[i][j]-2]==a){
                                        CurrentInv[a]=CurrentInv[a]+onlyBike[i][j][0][d]*countOD[i][j]*x[i][j][0][d];

                                    }}
                            }}
                        if(nSizeO[i][j]!=0){
                            for(int k=1; k<(int)nSizeO[i][j]+1; k++){
                                if( jaggedO[i][j][k-1]==b){
                                    if(nSizeD[i][j]!=0){
                                        for(int d=(int)nSizeO[i][j]+2; d<(int)nSizeD[i][j]+(int)nSizeO[i][j]+2; d++){
                                            if( jaggedD[i][j][d-(int)nSizeO[i][j]-2]==a){
                                                CurrentInv[a]=CurrentInv[a]+onlyBike[i][j][k][d]*countOD[i][j]*x[i][j][k][d];

                                            }}}
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        //countOD2[a][b]=countOD[i][j];
                        if(i==a){
                            if(j==b){
                                CurrentInv[a]=CurrentInv[a]-onlyBike[i][j][0][(int)nSizeO[i][j]+1]*countOD[i][j]*x[i][j][0][(int)nSizeO[i][j]+1];
                            }
                        }
                        if( i==a){
                            if(nSizeO[i][j]!=0){
                                for(int k=1; k<(int)nSizeO[i][j]+1; k++){
                                    if( jaggedO[i][j][k-1]==b){
                                        CurrentInv[a]=CurrentInv[a]-onlyBike[i][j][0][k]*countOD[i][j]*x[i][j][0][k];
                                    }}}}

                        if( i==a){
                            if(nSizeD[i][j]!=0){
                                for(int d=(int)nSizeO[i][j]+2; d<(int)nSizeD[i][j]+(int)nSizeO[i][j]+2; d++){
                                    if( jaggedD[i][j][d-(int)nSizeO[i][j]-2]==b){
                                        CurrentInv[a]=CurrentInv[a]-onlyBike[i][j][0][d]*countOD[i][j]*x[i][j][0][d];
                                    }}}}


                        //countOD2[a][b]=countOD[i][j]; 
                        if(nSizeO[i][j]!=0){
                            for(int k=1; k<(int)nSizeO[i][j]+1; k++){
                                if( jaggedO[i][j][k-1]==a){
                                    if(nSizeD[i][j]!=0){
                                        for(int d=(int)nSizeO[i][j]+2; d<(int)nSizeD[i][j]+(int)nSizeO[i][j]+2; d++){
                                            if( jaggedD[i][j][d-(int)nSizeO[i][j]-2]==b){
                                                CurrentInv[a]=CurrentInv[a]-onlyBike[i][j][k][d]*countOD[i][j]*x[i][j][k][d];
                                            }}}
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        //countOD2[a][b]=countOD[i][j]; 
                        if(nSizeO[i][j]!=0){
                            for(int k=1; k<(int)nSizeO[i][j]+1; k++){
                                if( jaggedO[i][j][k-1]==a){
                                    if( j==b){
                                        CurrentInv[a]=CurrentInv[a]-onlyBike[i][j][k][(int)nSizeO[i][j]+1]*countOD[i][j]*x[i][j][k][(int)nSizeO[i][j]+1];
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
long end6 = System.currentTimeMillis();
_solutiontime = (end6 - start6);
System.out.println(" currentinvtime: "+_solutiontime);
```

Comment: How do you know that this is the specific part that's causing the delay?

Comment: Is this code extracted into a separate method that is called exactly the same using both heuristic algorithms or is it copied and pasted twice?

Comment: Can you please add two sections to your answer, giving the values of the following variables in the slow and fast case? _invIndex, no1, _destNE. Also, if you could give rough approximate values for nSizeD and nSizeO elements, that would be helpful. Are your incentives vectors the same in both cases, or different? If different, does this account for the longer processing times in the slow case?

Comment: @Daniel I assume he ran the code and observed the time it took to run; see the last line of his sample.

Comment: @Patrick87 mmm ok, good call.

Comment: @Daniel: I have checked execution time for all the parts of the code. This part alone takes 5 minutes, the rest of the parts take a few seconds.

Comment: @user3255914 Again - I can't begin to help until you give more information. At most, all I can say now is "it takes a different amount of time because the input is different." Check your input.

Comment: @dkatzel: It was copied and pasted twice.

Comment: @Patrick87: The variables you mentioned are data arrays. The values of _invIndex, no1, _destNE are 202 in both cases. nSizeD and nSizeO are also read from .txt files and are the same for both programs. There values can be from 0 to 5. They represent the number of neighborhood points of a particular point in a network. The incentives vector is different but it does not come into play in this part of the code. The incentives vector is used in the minimum cost network flow problem which gives out x[][][][]=1 for certain links. This 'x' is then used to calculate the CurrentInv in the code above.

Comment: @Patrick87 Yes, I understand. I will check the input arrays again. The only thing different will be the the values of variable 'x' as it is different for different incentives vector. The rest of the variables are read from .txt files and are same for both programs.